# My SQL is taking 40 seconds to run, yet PHP will perform the same operation much quicker. Why is that?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got the following SQL:

```
SELECT t1.thread,t1.sender,t1.recipient,t1.subject,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `student-messages-seen` WHERE messageID = t1.id) AS count,
        (SELECT id FROM `student-messages-seen` WHERE messageID = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `student-messages` t3 WHERE t3.thread = t1.thread) AND userID = 4) AS seen,
        (SELECT ts FROM `student-messages` WHERE thread = t1.thread ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) AS ts
        FROM `student-messages` t1 
        WHERE (sender = 4 OR recipient = 4) 
        AND id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM `student-messages` WHERE thread = t1.thread)
        GROUP BY thread ORDER BY ts DESC
```

There's two tables, `student-messages` and `student-messages-seen`.  I can post the structure of the tables if nessessary.

The above SQL statement takes 40 seconds (!) to run! I get that theres a bunch of embedded statements in there, but that's really far to long.

What I need to understand is:

1. Why is this taking so long?
2. If I were to write the statements separately in PHP, the whole process would be much much quicker.  Why is that?
3. How can I speed the process up?

Comment: Use correct indexes and write correct joins. ALSO consider using CTE
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: @Kapsonfire so what is a 'correct' join?  If I am doing it wrong please write an answer to correct me.

Comment: You are doing implicit joins... I won't write the whole query for you but you should explain what exactly you are trying to achive? It looks like you are looking for the newest threads in a forum? - Instead of getting the latest timestamp in a query use the aggregate function MAX since you are already grouping... and every column you are selecting/grouping should be a index... in your case student-messages.thread AND student-messages-seen.messageID should be a index

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Query using a a set of at least 5 Subqueries, which is coplicated ;).

I can assure that the reasons why a this Query is slow is related to the INDEXES! Please ensure that you have for each subquery query also the correct Indexes set. By setting the INDEXES in the table, you will fire up your performance

If you're using MYSQL, you could use EXPLAIN to get more information about the Indexes.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    t1.thread,
    t1.sender,
    t1.recipient,
    t1.subject,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `student-messages-seen` WHERE messageID = t1.id) AS count,
   (SELECT id FROM `student-messages-seen` WHERE messageID = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `student-messages` t3 WHERE t3.thread = t1.thread) AND userID = 4) AS seen,
   (SELECT ts FROM `student-messages` WHERE thread = t1.thread ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) AS ts
   FROM `student-messages` t1 
   WHERE (sender = 4 OR recipient = 4) 
   AND id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM `student-messages` WHERE thread = t1.thread)
   GROUP BY thread ORDER BY ts DESC
```

Need to ensure that this tables have the INDEX set:

**Table student-messages**

Index for column sender

Index for column recipient

Index for column thread

**Table student-messages-seen**

Index for column messageID

Index for column messageID + column userID

Comment: O wow! Thank you!  I have never used indexes before today and I just watched a video: 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsG1XaZEa78 and it explained everything so well.  The query now takes 0.0053 seconds now thanks to the indexes you told me to create.  How did you decide which indexes to use?

Comment: Cool @Chud37 :), happy you solved the issue. Depends on the Table entries if you need INDEXES or not. If a table has less than 500 entries than you probably might need no INDEXES. If you assume that a table will have more than 500 entries than you would need to create them...

In QUERY STATEMENTS which use WHERE or AND etc than for this clauses you need the INDEX... I just analyzed your queries where you use WHERE, AND, OR and identified which columns need the INDEX set. 

I also think there are some very good videos on YouTube who are pretty good.